# How to click an href within HTML table if cell value within same row equals value in Excel workbook

Tags: html, vba, excel, html-table

I'm attempting to automate the population of a webform based on values in an excel template.  I've successfully been able to access the site and navigate through a few clicks with the VBA code below.  Next, I need to tackle an HTML table.  I'm needing to click the href containing inner text "reconcile" if a cell in the same row of the HTML table equals a value keyed into my Excel workbook.  The HTML table contains many rows, I've truncated the HTML code below to just include 2 rows for illustration (bullets 2 and 3).  Using row "bullet 2" for example, I'm need to click the href within that row if a cell in my workbook equals "2205021" ("2205021" is a uniquely identifiable cell value in both the HTML table and my Excel workbook).

Please note that I'm not wanting to reference any uniquely identifiable attributes of the href such as "id" because I'm needing the code to be written generally to apply to all of my Excel templates, relying only on the uniquely identifiable cell value eluded to above (unless there's a way to do this that still achieves my desired result).

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Grant

My VBA code thus far:

```
Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub

Sub FillInternetForm()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate "https://Website I'm Navigating To"
ie.Visible = True

ieBusy ie

Set AllHyperLinks = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each Hyper_link In AllHyperLinks
    If Hyper_link.innerText = "Reconciliations" Then
        Hyper_link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

ieBusy ie

Dim mySelection As String, mySelObj As Object
Set mySelObj = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ucDashboardPreparer_ucDashboardSettings_ctl00_ddlRoles")

mySelection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("b2").Value    
Select Case mySelection
Case "Preparer", "Reviewer", "Approver"
Case Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Selection!"
    ie.Quit
    Exit Sub
End Select

mySelObj.Value = mySelection

ieBusy ie

Set mySelObj = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_ucDashboardPreparer_ucDashboardSettings_ctl00_ddlEffectiveDate")

mySelection = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("c8").Value    
Select Case mySelection
Case "12/31/2017" 'I'll ref a cell in my workbook here once code is built out
Case Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Selection!"
    ie.Quit
    Exit Sub
End Select
```

---

Relevant HTML Code:

```htm
1."<table class=""rgMasterTable"" 
id=""ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00"" style=""border-width: 
0px; width: 100%; table-layout: auto; empty-cells: show;"" border=""0"" 
cellspacing=""1"" cellpadding=""2"">"

  <tbody>
2. <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00__0" style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="javascript:needToConfirm = false;">
    <td style="display: none;">29937</td><td style="display: none;">0</td><td style="display: none;">3199</td><td style="display: none;">&nbsp;</td><td style="display: none;">False</td><td style="display: none;">False</td><td>
                            <img title="Not Started" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_StatusIcon" style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Not Started" src="../images/document_plain_new.gif">
                        </td><td>
                            <a tabindex="33" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_lnkReconcile" onclick="javascript:return CheckInterval();" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$assignedAccountsGrid$ctl00$ctl04$lnkReconcile','')">Reconcile</a>
                        </td><td>US</td><td>CORP</td><td>DOM</td><td>2205021</td><td>XX</td><td>XX</td><td>XX</td><td>0L</td><td>Group Insurance Withholding</td><td align="center">12/31/2017</td><td align="center" class="Delinquent">1/28/2018</td><td align="right">10,920.72</td><td align="right">0.00</td><td>

                        </td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">10,920.72</td><td>Grant Bangerter</td><td>Ryan Smith</td><td>
                            <span id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_lblResponsibilty">Primary</span>
                        </td><td style="display: none;">False</td>
3. </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00__1" style="white-space: nowrap;" onclick="javascript:needToConfirm = false;">
    <td style="display: none;">28148</td><td style="display: none;">0</td><td style="display: none;">3199</td><td style="display: none;">&nbsp;</td><td style="display: none;">False</td><td style="display: none;">False</td><td>
                            <img title="Not Started" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_StatusIcon" style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Not Started" src="../images/document_plain_new.gif">
                        </td><td>
                            <a tabindex="33" id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_lnkReconcile" onclick="javascript:return CheckInterval();" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$assignedAccountsGrid$ctl00$ctl06$lnkReconcile','')">Reconcile</a>
                        </td><td>US</td><td>CORP</td><td>DOM</td><td>GRP.2203015</td><td>XX</td><td>XX</td><td>XX</td><td>0L</td><td>Accrued Dental Insurance Expense</td><td align="center">12/31/2017</td><td align="center" class="Delinquent">1/28/2018</td><td align="right">-12,751,041.02</td><td align="right">0.00</td><td>

                        </td><td align="right">&nbsp;</td><td align="right">-12,751,041.02</td><td>Grant Bangerter</td><td>Ryan Smith</td><td>
                            <span id="ctl00_MainContent_assignedAccountsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_lblResponsibilty">Primary</span>
                        </td><td style="display: none;">False</td>
```

I can provide further HTML code from webform if needed.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a great time for you to consider life beyond Microsoft Office - Proceed w/ the Web/RESTful/Browsers. You might start by creating automation to dump data out of Office and into maybe a JSON file? From there, it's easy sailing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML from your post doesn't have any cell equal to `2205021`. Though there's one equal to `GRP.2203015`.

To find and click the `Reconcile` link from the row with "GRP.2203015" :

```
Dim elmID As Object, elmLink As Object

' get the cell in column 12 with text "GRP.2203015" '
Set elmID = FindElement(ie.document, "table tr td:nth-child(12)", text:="GRP.2203015")

' get the link in the parent row with text "Reconcile"
Set elmLink = FindElement(elmID.parentElement, "td a", text:="Reconcile")

' click the link '
elmLink.Click
```

And for the `FindElement` function:

```
Public Function FindElement(context As Object, selector As String, Optional text) As Object

    For Each FindElement In context.querySelectorAll(selector)
        If IsMissing(text) Or FindElement.innerText Like text Then Exit Function
    Next

    Err.Raise 9, , "Element not found for selector:" & selector & " text:" & text
End Function
```

Note that you could also search for `text="*2203015"` to ignore the prefix.

Comment: I like your function. I have a feeling I would use that at some point myself. +1

Comment: @Florent B. This worked flawlessly - thank you for your response - Grant

Answer (score 1):

This may take a few attempts as it's somewhat difficult to ensure the validity of my answer without the source in front of me.

What you can do is first grab the table. In the following example, your table will be set to the variable `t`.

Next, you can look inside all of the tags (`tr` - for table rows) within your table to find your value (`yourVal`), and set that to the variable `r` while you perform a click.

```
Sub FillInternetForm()

    Dim ie As Object


    ' ... add'l code ...


    'Grab the table itself
    Dim t As Object, htmlTbls As Object
    Set htmlTbls = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each t In htmlTbls
        If t.className = "rgMasterTable" Then Exit For
    Next t

    'Grab the cell containing your value
    Dim yourVal As Long, tCell As Object, tCells As Object
    yourVal = 2205021
    Dim r As Object, rColl As Object    'rColl is collection of rows in your table
    Set rColl = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")    ' tr = table row
    For Each r In rColl

        'TRY IT AS A STRING
        If r.outerHTML Like "*" & CStr(yourVal) & "*" Then
            MsgBox "FOUND IT (STRING)! TRYING TO CLICK NOW"  ' for debugging purposes
            r.Click
            Exit For
        End If

        'TRY IT AS A LONG
        Set tCells = r.getElementsByTagName("td")
        For Each tCell In tCells
            If tCell.innerText = yourVal Or _
                    tCell.innerText Like "*" & CStr(yourVal) & "*" Then
                MsgBox "FOUND IT (ALTERNATE). ATTEMPTING TO CLICK NOW"
                r.Click
                tCell.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next tCell

    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: @K.Davis  -  Thank you for your response.  Your suggested code doesn't seem to be getting me there yet.  No error messages, just no action on the webform.  Thank you,  Grant

Comment: @GrantBangerter So if you didn't get the msgbox prompt (intended to check if `a` was found) then try to replace `a.innerHTML` with `a.outerHTML`.... You  can also try `a.innerText` & `a.outerText` to see if you have any success.

Comment: @K.Davis - It may also be relevant to share that I changed our "debugger" code from "If" to "If Not" and ran the code with a result of "True" in the Excel message box.

Comment: @GrantBangerter Yeah it's definitely an issue with the object not being set. Let me know how the above 3 changes work for you.

Comment: @K.Davis - I changed the debugger code back to your original and tried your three suggestions with the result of no MsgBox prompt in my excel workbook - Grant

Comment: @GrantBangerter Very interesting. Maybe it's `t` that's not being set. I'll update my code to include another msgbox test to see if `t` is found. - Updated. LMK if you get the msgbox for `Found t!`.

Comment: @K.Davis - I updated the code to reflect your latest changes.  After executing, the message box returned "Found t!" in my workbook.

Comment: @GrantBangerter okay, I see what happened. The `a` tag terminated prior to your value. I updated to look in the entire row with the `tr` tag. See if that works.

Comment: @K.Davis - I'm getting "Compile error: Invalid Next control variable reference."  I click ok to the error and it highlights the "a" within the "Next a" code line right before "End Sub."  Should the "a" be interchanged with "r"?

Comment: @GrantBangerter I'm sorry it should be `Next r`. Or just `Next` without the keyword.

Comment: @K.Davis - I made that update  - When I ran the code I got "Run-time error '424' Object required."  When I clicked "debug" on the error prompt, the row "For Each r in In rColl" was highlighted.  I updated "Set aColl = ...." line to "Set rColl = ..." and executed with no action taken on the web page.  I tried your three other reiterations of "a.inner/outer/html/text" suggested earlier with no action on the webform and no Msg box prompt within my workbook.

Comment: @GrantBangerter And you are sure that your value `2205021` is still in the html code? My only other thought would be to try it as a long other than a string. I will update code in a moment. - UPDATED

Comment: I am certain my value "2205021" is still in the HTML code.  I just double checked.  When I execute the update code I'm prompted with error "run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method." When I click "debug" from the error message prompt window, the Code lines "If tCell.Value = yourVal Or tCell.innerText = yourVal Or _
                    tCell.innerText Like "*" & CStr(yourVal) & "*" Then" are yellow highlighted.  Thanks, Grant

Comment: @GrantBangerter That would be because table cells do not have a `.value` property. I apologize I wasn't thinking (Early binding would have prevented that BTW). I updated code to remove that property. If this new code doesn't work I will set a bounty on your question to raise alot more awareness (once your question is eligible).

Comment: @K.Davis - I updated my code to reflect your changes.  When I execute, I'm prompted with no error messages, however, no action is taken on the webform and no MsgBoxs populate within my workbook.  Thanks you very much for your help - Grant

Comment: @GrantBangerter Tomorrow I should be able to place a bounty on this question. Feel bad for wasting your time with these trial and error solutions. Maybe someone with more HTML knowledge or XMLHTTP can provide more assistance.

Comment: @K.Davis  Thank you very much for your help!  No need for apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand your questions, but maybe something like this will get you going in the right direction.

```
For each l in ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a") 
    If l.ClassName = "click_button" Then
        l.Click
    Exit For
Next
```

OR

```
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieAnchors As Object
Dim Anchor As Object

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieAnchors = ieDoc.Anchors

For Each Anchor In ieAnchors
If Anchor.innerHTML = "Button" Then
Anchor.Click
Exit For
End If
Next Anchor
```

OR

```
for each ele in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
   if instr(ele.innerhtml, "yes.gif") > 0 then ele.click: exit for
next
```

Finally, the link below has some good ideas which may help you out.

http://automatetheweb.net/vba-getelementsbytagname-method/